# TYPO3 Extension Manager doesn't work

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

I've uploaded TYPO3 CMS version 6.0 on my web server and successfully installed it. The problem is when i try to access Extension Manager, it gives me following error

```
Could not determine the child object type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove TYPO3 cache files from typo3temp folder then reload BE and try again.
I had the same problem and this helped me.